# Android setting with TextView right to left

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left

I need to set a text in an Android TextView that is combined with Arabic letters and in the middle I have 123.doc

In strings.xml:

```
<string name="message">حفظ باسم  1% وإرسال</string>
```

(Translated to “Save as 123.doc and send”)

And then in the code:

```
String string = getString(R.string.message);
String message = string.replace("%1", "123.doc");
```

The output is wrong:
حفظ باسم  doc.123  وإرسال
(should be 123.doc)

I’ve tried setting text gravity, text alignment and what was suggested here: [Android setting with TextView for Hebrew text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302221/android-setting-with-textview-for-hebrew-text/6302325#6302325)
With no help…

Can anyone help please?
Thanx so much!

Update:
Here is an image of my code, suggested by Farhad Faghihi's answer and the output (Don't mind the meaning of the string, I've just added a random word for testing):
[image]

Comment: I've added what is relevant...

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448746/android-textview-right-alignment-on-a-right-to-left-device)..May help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally found a way to get it right! In case someone wants to know, this is how (it’s so simple, I can’t believe nobody suggested it before) :

```
String filename = 123.doc
String message = s1 + "\u202A" + fileName + "\u202C" + s2;
```

Where s1 and s2 are strings in a RtL language.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that you can use to reformat texts from non-latin languages.

You may want to have a look at the "Better Arabic Resharper " on github.

and also, since I've had projects which were concerned with displaying arabic and persian text (both share 29 alphabet letters AFAIK), I used a very handy library called Farsi.java.

This class has two main methods :

1- Convert(string) - reformats plain text of arabic/persian

2- ConvertBackToRealFarsi(string) - reformats plain text of arabic/persian that is combined with punctuation marks, numbers, english letters , ....

Since arabic has less alphabet letters than Persian, you can use this library smoothly.

the code :

```
package com.example.fasri;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public final class Farsi {

public static boolean isFarsiConversionNeeded = true;

private final static String szLamAndAlef = Character
        .toString((char) 0xfedf)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam + Alef

private final static String szLamStickAndAlef = Character
        .toString((char) 0xfee0)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xfe8e); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                                // Alef

private final static String szLa = Character.toString((char) 0xfefb); // La
private final static String szLaStick = Character.toString((char) 0xfefc); // La
                                                                            // (Sticky!!!)

private final static String szLamAndAlefWoosim = Character
        .toString((char) 0xe1)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam + Alef

private final static String szLamStickAndAlefWoosim = Character
        .toString((char) 0x90)
        + Character.toString((char) 0xbb); // Lam (Sticky !!!)+
                                            // Alef

private final static String szLaWoosim = Character.toString((char) 0xd9); // La
private final static String szLaStickWoosim = Character
        .toString((char) 0xd9); // La

// (Sticky!!!)

private static final class struc {
    public char character;
    public char endGlyph;
    public char iniGlyph;
    public char midGlyph;
    public char isoGlyph;

    public struc(char Character, char EndGlyph, char IniGlyph,
            char MidGlyph, char IsoGlyph) {
        character = Character;
        endGlyph = EndGlyph;
        iniGlyph = IniGlyph;
        midGlyph = MidGlyph;
        isoGlyph = IsoGlyph;
    }
}

static struc[] arrStruc = {
        new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab,
                (char) 0xfeac, (char) 0xfeab),
        new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9,
                (char) 0xfeaa, (char) 0xfea9),
        new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0xfe9e, (char) 0xfe9f,
                (char) 0xfea0, (char) 0xfe9d),
        new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0xfea2, (char) 0xfea3,
                (char) 0xfea4, (char) 0xfea1),
        new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0xfea6, (char) 0xfea7,
                (char) 0xfea8, (char) 0xfea5),
        new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xfeea, (char) 0xfeeb,
                (char) 0xfeec, (char) 0xfee9),
        new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xfeca, (char) 0xfecb,
                (char) 0xfecc, (char) 0xfec9),
        new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xfece, (char) 0xfecf,
                (char) 0xfed0, (char) 0xfecd),
        new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xfed2, (char) 0xfed3,
                (char) 0xfed4, (char) 0xfed1),
        new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xfed6, (char) 0xfed7,
                (char) 0xfed8, (char) 0xfed5),
        new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xfe9a, (char) 0xfe9b,
                (char) 0xfe9c, (char) 0xfe99),
        new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xfeba, (char) 0xfebb,
                (char) 0xfebc, (char) 0xfeb9),
        new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xfebe, (char) 0xfebf,
                (char) 0xfec0, (char) 0xfebd),
        new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xfec2, (char) 0xfec3,
                (char) 0xfec4, (char) 0xfec1),
        new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xfeda, (char) 0xfedb,
                (char) 0xfedc, (char) 0xfed9),
        new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xfee2, (char) 0xfee3,
                (char) 0xfee4, (char) 0xfee1),
        new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xfee6, (char) 0xfee7,
                (char) 0xfee8, (char) 0xfee5),
        new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xfe96, (char) 0xfe97,
                (char) 0xfe98, (char) 0xfe95),
        new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d,
                (char) 0xfe8e, (char) 0xfe8d),
        new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xfede, (char) 0xfedf,
                (char) 0xfee0, (char) 0xfedd),
        new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xfe90, (char) 0xfe91,
                (char) 0xfe92, (char) 0xfe8f),
        new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xfef2, (char) 0xfef3,
                (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfef1),
        new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xfeb2, (char) 0xfeb3,
                (char) 0xfeb4, (char) 0xfeb1),
        new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xfeb6, (char) 0xfeb7,
                (char) 0xfeb8, (char) 0xfeb5),
        new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xfec6, (char) 0xfec7,
                (char) 0xfec8, (char) 0xfec5),
        new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf,
                (char) 0xfeb0, (char) 0xfeaf),
        new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed,
                (char) 0xfeee, (char) 0xfeed),
        new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xfe94, (char) 0xfe93,
                (char) 0xfe93, (char) 0xfe93),
        new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef,
                (char) 0xfef0, (char) 0xfeef),
        new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead,
                (char) 0xfeae, (char) 0xfead),
        new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85,
                (char) 0xfe86, (char) 0xfe85),
        new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80,
                (char) 0xfe80, (char) 0xfe80),
        new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xfe8a, (char) 0xfe8b,
                (char) 0xfe8c, (char) 0xfe89),
        new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83,
                (char) 0xfe84, (char) 0xfe83),
        new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81,
                (char) 0xfe82, (char) 0xfe81),
        new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87,
                (char) 0xfe88, (char) 0xfe87),
        new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xfb57, (char) 0xfb58,
                (char) 0xfb59, (char) 0xfb56), // peh
        new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0xfb7b, (char) 0xfb7c,
                (char) 0xfb7d, (char) 0xfb7a), // cheh
        new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a,
                (char) 0xfb8b, (char) 0xfb8a), // jeh
        new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xfb8f, (char) 0xfb90,
                (char) 0xfb91, (char) 0xfb8e), // keheh
        new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xfb93, (char) 0xfb94,
                (char) 0xfb95, (char) 0xfb92), // gaf
        // new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfbfe,
        // (char) 0xfbff, (char) 0xfbfc), // Farsi yeh
        new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xfbfd, (char) 0xfef3,
                (char) 0xfef4, (char) 0xfbfc), // Arabic yeh
        new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4,
                (char) 0xfba5, (char) 0xfba4) // heh with yeh
};

static struc[] arrStrucWoosim = {
        new struc((char) 0x630, (char) 0xb5, (char) 0x82, (char) 0xb5,
                (char) 0x82),
        new struc((char) 0x62f, (char) 0xb4, (char) 0x81, (char) 0xb4,
                (char) 0x81),
        new struc((char) 0x62c, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                (char) 0xbf),
        new struc((char) 0x62d, (char) 0x9c, (char) 0xb2, (char) 0xfa,
                (char) 0xc0),
        new struc((char) 0x62e, (char) 0x9d, (char) 0xb3, (char) 0xfe,
                (char) 0xc1),
        new struc((char) 0x647, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                (char) 0xd5),
        new struc((char) 0x639, (char) 0xc9, (char) 0xd3, (char) 0x8b,
                (char) 0xa4),
        new struc((char) 0x63a, (char) 0xca, (char) 0xdd, (char) 0x8c,
                (char) 0xa5),
        new struc((char) 0x641, (char) 0xa6, (char) 0xde, (char) 0x8d,
                (char) 0xcc),
        new struc((char) 0x642, (char) 0xa7, (char) 0xdf, (char) 0x8e,
                (char) 0xce),
        new struc((char) 0x62b, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                (char) 0x99),
        new struc((char) 0x635, (char) 0xc4, (char) 0xc8, (char) 0x87,
                (char) 0xa0),
        new struc((char) 0x636, (char) 0xc5, (char) 0xcb, (char) 0x88,
                (char) 0xa1),
        new struc((char) 0x637, (char) 0xc6, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                (char) 0xa2),
        new struc((char) 0x643, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                (char) 0xa8),
        new struc((char) 0x645, (char) 0xd2, (char) 0xe2, (char) 0x91,
                (char) 0xaa),
        new struc((char) 0x646, (char) 0xd4, (char) 0xe3, (char) 0x92,
                (char) 0xab),
        new struc((char) 0x62a, (char) 0xbd, (char) 0xaf, (char) 0xea,
                (char) 0x99),
        new struc((char) 0x627, (char) 0xbb, (char) 0x80, (char) 0xbb,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x644, (char) 0xd1, (char) 0xe1, (char) 0x90,
                (char) 0xa9),
        new struc((char) 0x628, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                (char) 0x98),
        new struc((char) 0x64a, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                (char) 0xdc),
        new struc((char) 0x633, (char) 0xc2, (char) 0xb8, (char) 0xb8,
                (char) 0x9e),
        new struc((char) 0x634, (char) 0xc3, (char) 0xb9, (char) 0xb9,
                (char) 0x9f),
        new struc((char) 0x638, (char) 0xc7, (char) 0xcd, (char) 0xcd,
                (char) 0xc7),
        new struc((char) 0x632, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                (char) 0xb7),
        new struc((char) 0x648, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94, (char) 0x94,
                (char) 0x94),
        new struc((char) 0x629, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda, (char) 0xda,
                (char) 0xda),
        new struc((char) 0x649, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                (char) 0xdc),
        new struc((char) 0x631, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6, (char) 0xb6,
                (char) 0xb6),
        new struc((char) 0x624, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7, (char) 0xe7,
                (char) 0xe7),
        new struc((char) 0x621, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba, (char) 0xba,
                (char) 0xba),
        new struc((char) 0x626, (char) 0xd7, (char) 0xe8, (char) 0x97,
                (char) 0xd7),
        new struc((char) 0x623, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x622, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x625, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80, (char) 0x80,
                (char) 0x80),
        new struc((char) 0x67e, (char) 0xbc, (char) 0xae, (char) 0xe9,
                (char) 0x98), // peh
        new struc((char) 0x686, (char) 0x9b, (char) 0xb1, (char) 0xf9,
                (char) 0xbf), // cheh
        new struc((char) 0x698, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7, (char) 0xb7,
                (char) 0xb7), // jeh
        new struc((char) 0x6a9, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                (char) 0xa8), // keheh
        new struc((char) 0x6af, (char) 0xcf, (char) 0xe0, (char) 0x8f,
                (char) 0xa8), // gaf
        new struc((char) 0x6cc, (char) 0xdc, (char) 0xe6, (char) 0x95,
                (char) 0xdc), // yeh
        new struc((char) 0x6c0, (char) 0xac, (char) 0xe4, (char) 0x93,
                (char) 0xd5) // heh with yeh
};

private static final int N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS = 43;

private static final String ArabicReverse(String s) {
    try {
        String Out = "", rev;
        s = MakeReverse(s);
        char[] chs = new char[s.length()];
        chs = s.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length()) {
            if ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9')) // isDigit(s[i]) ?
            {
                rev = "";
                while (i < s.length()
                        && ((chs[i] >= '0' && chs[i] <= '9') || chs[i] == '/')) // isDigit(s[i])
                                                                                // ?
                {
                    rev = rev + chs[i];
                    ++i;
                }
                rev = MakeReverse(rev);
                Out = Out + rev;
            } else {
                Out = Out + chs[i];
                ++i;
            }
        }
        s = Out;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // throw new Exception(
        // "An exception has occurred in ArabicReverse function.\\n"
        // + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return s;
}

private static final boolean isFromTheSet1(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
    char[] theSet1 = new char[] { (char) 0x62c, (char) 0x62d, (char) 0x62e,
            (char) 0x647, (char) 0x639, (char) 0x63a, (char) 0x641,
            (char) 0x642, (char) 0x62b, (char) 0x635, (char) 0x636,
            (char) 0x637, (char) 0x643, (char) 0x645, (char) 0x646,
            (char) 0x62a, (char) 0x644, (char) 0x628, (char) 0x64a,
            (char) 0x633, (char) 0x634, (char) 0x638, (char) 0x67e,
            (char) 0x686, (char) 0x6a9, (char) 0x6af, (char) 0x6cc,
            (char) 0x626 };
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 28) {
        if (ch == theSet1[i])
            return true;
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}

private static final boolean isFromTheSet2(/* WCHAR */char ch) {
    char[] theSet2 = new char[] { (char) 0x627, (char) 0x623, (char) 0x625,
            (char) 0x622, (char) 0x62f, (char) 0x630, (char) 0x631,
            (char) 0x632, (char) 0x648, (char) 0x624, (char) 0x629,
            (char) 0x649, (char) 0x698, (char) 0x6c0 };
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 14) {
        if (ch == theSet2[i])
            return true;
        ++i;
    }
    return false;
}

private static final String MakeReverse(String text) {
    String Result = "";
    char[] Ctext = new char[text.length()];
    Ctext = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = (text.length()) - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Result += Ctext[i];
    }
    return Result;
}

public static final String ConvertBackToRealFarsi(String In) {

    if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
        return In;
    }

    String strOut = "";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
    chIn = In.toCharArray();

    for (i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (j = 0; j < arrStruc.length; j++) {
            if (chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].midGlyph ||
                    chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].iniGlyph ||
                    chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].endGlyph ||
                    chIn[i] == arrStruc[j].isoGlyph) {
                strBuilder.append(arrStruc[j].character);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            strBuilder.append(chIn[i]);
    }

    strOut = strBuilder.toString();
    strOut = strOut.replace(szLa, "áÇ");
    strOut = strOut.replace(szLaStick, "áÇ");

    return strOut;
}

public static final String ConvertForDrawOnBitmap(String In) {
    return ArabicReverse(Convert(In));
}

public static final String Convert(String In) {

    if (!isFarsiConversionNeeded) {
        return In;
    }

    boolean linkBefore, linkAfter;
    String Out = In;
    char[] chOut = new char[Out.length()];
    chOut = Out.toCharArray();
    char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
    chIn = In.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
        /* WCHAR */
        char ch = chIn[i];
        if ((ch >= (char) 0x0621 && ch <= (char) 0x064a)
                || (ch == (char) 0x067e) || (ch == (char) 0x0686)
                || (ch == (char) 0x0698) || (ch == (char) 0x06a9)
                || (ch == (char) 0x06af) || (ch == (char) 0x06cc)
                || (ch == (char) 0x06c0)) // is a Farsi character?
        {
            int idx = 0;
            while (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                if (arrStruc[idx].character == chIn[i])
                    break;
                ++idx;
            }

            if (i == In.length() - 1)
                linkAfter = false;
            else
                linkAfter = (isFromTheSet1(chIn[i + 1]) || isFromTheSet2(chIn[i + 1]));
            if (i == 0)
                linkBefore = false;
            else
                linkBefore = isFromTheSet1(chIn[i - 1]);
            if (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                if (linkBefore && linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].midGlyph;
                if (linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].endGlyph;
                if (!linkBefore && linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].iniGlyph;
                if (!linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                    chOut[i] = arrStruc[idx].isoGlyph;
            } else {
                chOut[i] = chIn[i];
            }
        } else {
            chOut[i] = chIn[i];
        }
    }
    Out = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < chOut.length; j++)
        Out += chOut[j];
    // Out = ArabicReverse(Out);

    Out = Out.replace((char) 0x200c, ' '); // Change NO SPACE to SPACE

    Out = Out.replace(szLamAndAlef, szLa); // Join 'Lam' and 'Alef' and
                                            // make 'La'
    Out = Out.replace(szLamStickAndAlef, szLaStick); // Join 'Lam Stick'
                                                        // and 'Alef'
                                                        // and make 'La
                                                        // Stick'

    return reorderWords(Out);

}

private final static String reorderWords(String strIn)
{

    final int ST_RTL = 0;
    final int ST_LTR = 1;

    String strOut = "";
    String prevWord = "";
    int state = ST_RTL;
    char[] arr = strIn.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arr.length) {
        if (charIsLTR(arr[i]) && state != ST_LTR)
        {
            // state changed to LTR
            state = ST_LTR;
            strOut = prevWord + strOut;
            prevWord = "";
            prevWord += arr[i];
        }
        else if (charIsRTL(arr[i]) && state != ST_RTL)
        {
            // state changed to RTL
            state = ST_RTL;
            strOut = prevWord + strOut;
            prevWord = "";
            prevWord += arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            // state is not changed
            prevWord += arr[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    strOut = prevWord + strOut;

    return strOut;

}

private final static boolean charIsLTR(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= (char) 65 & ch <= (char) 122)
            |
            Character.isDigit(ch);
}

private final static boolean charIsRTL(char ch)
{
    return ch >= (char) 0x0621;
}

public static final String ConvertForPrinterWoosim(String In) {
    try {

        boolean linkBefore, linkAfter;
        String Out = In;
        char[] chOut = new char[Out.length()];
        chOut = Out.toCharArray();
        char[] chIn = new char[In.length()];
        chIn = In.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < In.length(); i++) {
            /* WCHAR */
            char ch = chIn[i];
            if ((ch >= (char) 0x0621 && ch <= (char) 0x064a)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x067e) || (ch == (char) 0x0686)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x0698) || (ch == (char) 0x06a9)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x06af) || (ch == (char) 0x06cc)
                    || (ch == (char) 0x06c0)) // is an Arabic character?
            {
                int idx = 0;
                while (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                    if (arrStrucWoosim[idx].character == chIn[i])
                        break;
                    ++idx;
                }

                if (i == In.length() - 1)
                    linkAfter = false;
                else
                    linkAfter = (isFromTheSet1(chIn[i + 1]) || isFromTheSet2(chIn[i + 1]));
                if (i == 0)
                    linkBefore = false;
                else
                    linkBefore = isFromTheSet1(chIn[i - 1]);
                if (idx < N_DISTINCT_CHARACTERS) {
                    if (linkBefore && linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStrucWoosim[idx].midGlyph;
                    if (linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStrucWoosim[idx].endGlyph;
                    if (!linkBefore && linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStrucWoosim[idx].iniGlyph;
                    if (!linkBefore && !linkAfter)
                        chOut[i] = arrStrucWoosim[idx].isoGlyph;
                } else {
                    chOut[i] = chIn[i];
                }
            } else {
                chOut[i] = chIn[i];
            }
        }
        Out = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < chOut.length; j++)
            Out += chOut[j];
        // ArabicReverse(Out);

        Out = Out.replace((char) 0x200c, ' '); // Change NO SPACE to SPACE

        Out = Out.replace(szLamAndAlefWoosim, szLaWoosim); // Join 'Lam' and
                                                            // 'Alef' and
        // make 'La'
        Out = Out.replace(szLamStickAndAlefWoosim, szLaStickWoosim); // Join
                                                                        // 'Lam
                                                                        // Stick'
        // and 'Alef'
        // and make 'La
        // Stick'

        return Out;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // throw new
        // Exception("An exception has occurred in Arabize function.\\n" +
        // ex.getMessage());
        return "";
    }
}

private static Typeface typeface;

public static final Typeface GetFarsiFont(Context act) {
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(act.getAssets(),
                // "DroidSansFallback.ttf");
                "TAHOMA.TTF");
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

}

[you may even check this thread on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962704/how-to-support-arabic-text-in-android/7962813#7962813)

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve my problem...  output is still doc.123 instead of 123.doc

Comment: try to do sth like this : Farsi.ConvertBackToRealFarsi("the arabic string") + "123.doc" - you don't have to reformat the english part.

Comment: Output remains wrong... The Arabic part is coming out fine, it's just the combination of the numbers-dot-English that somehow ruins the string

Comment: even with the ConvertBackToRealFarsi() function? there are also two other convert functions on the Farsi.java. you can try them too

Comment: have you tried this : Farsi.ConvertBackToRealFarsi("the arabic string") + "123" + "." + "doc" - ?

Comment: can you post a picture of this incorrect input + the code you're using? I'm thinking you may have been missing something trivial

Comment: I spent at least 1 hour of trial and error and no result ! As I noticed the problem is with the punctuation marks and this issue exists with other non-western languages too. anyway, I found this link which will definitely help you. If it was useful, try to mark the answer as accepted, http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1779594/

Comment: unfortunately it didn't... I still don't have a solution